# Docker run <image> always errs with standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" on windows

Tags: docker

I tried to do a `docker-compose up` from my Dockerfile, but it failed with an error of `standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`

I've already tried everything including reinstalling docker but it seems to not work.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
  bundle_cache:
    driver: local

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    logging:
      driver: "none"
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"

  web-tracking:
    build:
      context: .
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "${RAILS_PORT}:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app:delegated
      - bundle_cache:/bundle
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3

EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR ./app

RUN \
  apt-get update -qq && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  nodejs \
  postgresql-client

ENV BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle \
  BUNDLE_BIN=/bundle/bin \
  GEM_HOME=/bundle
ENV PATH="${BUNDLE_BIN}:${PATH}"

COPY docker-entry.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/docker-entry.sh"]
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-entry.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# if the server was not shut down properly the pid file will need to be removed
if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi
bundle install
bundle exec "$@"
```

Comment: The Dockerfile sets `WORKDIR` to `./app` (==`${PWD}/app`). `docker-entry.sh` is copied there. But the `ENTRYPOINT` uses `/app`. I think the `WORKDIR` should also be `/app`.

Comment: @DazWilkin that's something I messed around with to try and get the `docker-compose` to work. That's not actually in the original file. But I can't correct it otherwise stack overflow will say that I posted too much code so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It's not good, the behavior depends on the base image, but here base image's working directory is `/`, so `/./app` just same as `/app`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is `docker-entry.sh`, you set this file on windows. On windows, the line breaker is `\r\n`, while you finally run it in linux container, the line breaker is `\n`.

So you should enter something like `git-bash`, then do `dos2unix docker-entry.sh` to change the format, rebuild & rerun it, it will be fine.

Another solution is install dos2unix when build and change the format in `Dockerfile`, like next (you may also need to change its permission):

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3

EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR ./app

RUN \
  apt-get update -qq && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  nodejs \
  postgresql-client \
  dos2unix

ENV BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle \
  BUNDLE_BIN=/bundle/bin \
  GEM_HOME=/bundle
ENV PATH="${BUNDLE_BIN}:${PATH}"

COPY docker-entry.sh .
RUN dos2unix ./docker-entry.sh && chmod 777 ./docker-entry.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/docker-entry.sh"]
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I run your stack without problem on Ubuntu 16.04. If you are runing on Windows, maybe you need use dos2unix to run docker-entry.sh script  (https://forums.docker.com/t/standard-init-linux-go-175-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file/20025)

When I started with docker, I tried to use docker-compose in the first time.
So, I realized that is very much dificult for me learn docker and docker-compose together,
because you lost in the mess of the command and config.
To start I recomend for you, try to use just the Dockerfile and connect the "postgres" and "web-tracking"
container with the docker network called 'user-defined bridges' (https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/);